# Adding new libraries to java

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to use a feature from the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) called StringUtils. However this requires you download the libary and add it so I can use the code `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;`. My problem is I am unsure of where to add it to so that I may compile my program in command prompt. I am also unaware of what file I should to add into the required folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not using any IDE or any other programs. I am only using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to try and write my code

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to make sure that the library (usually a JAR file) is in the classpath when you compile and run your application that uses the library.

The **classpath** is the set of JAR files and directories that Java uses to find Java class files.

See [PATH and CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials. (This is about setting the environment variables `PATH` and `CLASSPATH`).

As an alternative to setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, you can use the `-cp` or `-classpath` options of the `javac` and `java` commands:

```
javac -cp C:\MyProject\lib\somelibrary.jar;. com\mypackage\MyProgram.java

java -cp C:\MyProject\lib\somelibrary.jar;. com.mypackage.MyProgram
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any IDE, then include below line in your .java file.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

then we you compile the .java class from cmd prompt, include the apache commons jar in classpath. like

```
javac -cp ../commons**.jar your_class.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to point to it. [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Given the context of the question I assume you are not using maven or an IDE. If you are there are simpler ways.